# スマホ版のスタックオーバーフローでコメントの最低入力数を表示してほしい

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, モバイル

スタックオーバーフローのサイトにスマホからアクセスして質問や回答にコメントしようとしてもあまりにも短い文字数だとコメントできません。

コメントの最低文字数に満たない場合に「コメントを追加」というボタンを押した場合でも、何も表示されずコメントも投稿できません。

せめて、コメントが最低文字数に満たなかった場合は「あと何文字入力してください」と表示したりできると嬉しいです。

現状だと、コメントが投稿できない理由がわからず、「コメントを追加」ボタンを押しても無反応なため、ユーザーが混乱するかと思います。

[image: コメントの最低文字数がわからない]

改善を希望します。

Comment: 開発者に依頼しました。このバグが[英語版にも登録されています](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100053/add-comment-length-counter-on-the-mobile-site)。 （治すには時間がかかる場合もございますので、ご了承ください）

Answer (score 0, accepted):

モバイル版サイトを更新しました。確認よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 更新されていました。ありがとうございます